# Creating Dynamic R.drawable source and ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, dynamically-generated, android-drawable

I have an Activity which has variable `position` that comes from another activity. I handle this variable with `Intent` like below. (*Actually `position` is listView's position from another activity.*) and values of `position` variable are 0 to 200

I took my Extra, then assigned it to a string than I parsed it to an Integer. These are normal and easy for me and working.

```
Intent i            = getIntent();
String position     = i.getStringExtra("POSITION");
int position_to_int = Integer.parseInt(position);
```

But my problem is about resources.

Simply I want to put an image to my LinearLayout **dynamically** . I have some country flags and they named in format like `0.gif`, `1.gif`, `2.gif`, `3.gif` ...

My idea is using `position` variable's value for this purpose.

but when I try to use `position_to_int` variable for name of flag, Eclipse returning error normally. Because `R.drawble.XXX` values storing in `R.java`

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
// setting image resource
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.position_to_int);
```

**How can I use `position_to_int` variable to show an ImageView dynamically?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access it directly. You'll have to get the resource using its name:

```
private Drawable getDrawableResourceByName(int name) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("character_you_prefixed" + String.valueOf(name), "drawable", packageName);
    return getResources().getDrawable(resId);
}
```

Note that your resource names must begin with a letter, not a number, or else your project will not compile. Try adding a character to the beginning of each file name.

Comment: Can you change variable names to my question's variable names. (I am talking about position_to_int)

Comment: @hakiko Just call getDrawableResourceByName(position_to_int) when you need the drawable. Though if you can't figure out how to use the code I provided, you should consider picking up a Java book before working on Android.

Comment: @vmironov That's why we get the resource using its name, and not an ID

Comment: @Raghav Sood, yep, but we can't have a resource with name `0` or `1` or any another integer

Comment: @vmironov Yes, we can. Resources can contain a-z, 0-9 and underscores. However, it must begin with a letter

Comment: I set this method in my activity class then I call it in `imageView.setImageResource(getDrawableResourceByName(position_to_int)` but it is not working

Comment: Try using setImageDrawable() instead.

Comment: Thanks I got it. You are right. If resource does not start with letter, it is not working! Now working